# ¿Cómo hacer que un ciclo determine cuales números de una lista son primos y cuales no son primos?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, bucles, números-primos

teniendo una lista finita de números que son de tipo int por ejemplo:
lista = [20, 31, 87, 338,] y que me diga cuales elementos de la lista son primos y cuales no son primos
y que muestre al final del código:
20 no es primo
31 es primo
87 es primo
338 no es primo

```
import math
lista2 = [20, 30, 31, 45, 67]
for numero in lista2:
  cant_divisores = 0
  encontro_divisores = False
  limite=math.sqrt(a)
  i = 2
  while (i <= limite and not encontro_divisores):
      if a % i == 0:
          cant_divisores+=1
          encontro_divisores = True
      i+=1
  if cant_divisores==0 and a>1:
      print(a, " es primo")
  else:
      print(a, " no es primo")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te confundistes. Usaste `for numero in lista:`, pero luego dentro del código, siempre usaste la variable `a`.

Solución: cambia el `for numero` a `for a`.

Comprobación:

```
import math
lista2 = [20, 30, 31, 45, 67]
for a in lista2:
  cant_divisores = 0
  encontro_divisores = False
  limite=math.sqrt(a)
  i = 2
  while (i <= limite and not encontro_divisores):
      if a % i == 0:
          cant_divisores+=1
          encontro_divisores = True
      i+=1
  if cant_divisores==0 and a>1:
      print(a, " es primo")
  else:
      print(a, " no es primo")
```

produce:

```
20  no es primo
30  no es primo
31  es primo
45  no es primo
67  es primo
```